# Can I get a POCO from EF4's function import?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, poco, entity-framework-4, efpocoadapter

In the context of Entity Framework 4, the default behavior when adding a function import is to call it via `ExecuteFunction<T>()`, where `T` must apparently implement some property change notification stuff.  (In my case it's generating a complex type derived from `ComplexObject`.)

I don't need or want any change notifications, and I'm required to send POCOs up the line after these sproc calls.

Is there a way to get a POCO directly from an EF sproc call?  If not, does anyone have any recommendations on turning my sproc result into a POCO?

(I've played briefly with the [POCO Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2010/02/18/entity-framework-poco-template-updated-for-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx), but it doesn't seem to support stored procedures in any way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteFunction<T>` returns an `ObjectResult<T>`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can project the `T` onto anything via LINQ.  E.g.:

```
IEnumerable<MyPoco> = from f in Context.MyFunction()
                      select new MyPoco
                      {
                          A = f.A,
                          B = f.B
                      };
```

Comment: That's just wonderful compared to the alternatives I was considering - thank you!